# runif fails testu01's SmallCrush

Tags: r, random, mersenne-twister

I am seeing a failure of the R random number generator using [testu01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html) SmallCrush. This surprises me as the documentation says `runif` uses Mersenne Twister. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

I run

```
set.seed(42)
rs <- runif(n=51320000)
write(x=rs,file="foo.bar")
```

and then `SmallCrush` via

```
#include "bbattery.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  bbattery_SmallCrushFile("foo.bar");
}
```

and get a failure:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 Starting SmallCrush
                 Version: TestU01 1.2.3
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


***********************************************************
HOST = Hogsmill.local, Darwin

ufile_CreateReadText:   foo.bar


smarsa_BirthdaySpacings test:
-----------------------------------------------
   N =  1,  n = 5000000,  r =  0,    d = 1073741824,    t = 2,    p = 1


      Number of cells = d^t = 1152921504606846976
      Lambda = Poisson mean =      27.1051


----------------------------------------------------
Total expected number = N*Lambda      :      27.11
Total observed number                 :   67744
p-value of test                       :   eps      *****


-----------------------------------------------
CPU time used                    :  00:00:03.04

Generator state:
 10000000  numbers have been read
```

Comment: The standard python RNG passes: import random

random.seed(42)

for i in range(1,1 + 51320000//4):
    a = random.random()
    b = random.random()
    c = random.random()
    d = random.random()
    print(a,b,c,d)

Comment: i'm not certain - hence not being an answer - but I'd be concerned at the line `write(x=rs,file="foo.bar")` truncating your nicely generated uniform random numbers into 7 digit decimals in a way that doesn't retain the uniformity. You might be better to use `writeBin()` and read the binary file into SmallCrush

Comment: That sounds very plausible. Python wrote out doubles but it seems R writes out floats. I will try it shortly.

Comment: It isn't entirely true that R writes out floats. `write()` uses the number of digits specified by `options("digits")`, whether that is more or less than the number of digits stored internally. You could try `options(digits=22)` before writing the text file to reduce the truncation problem.

Comment: Thanks - did you want to answer the question and I can up vote it? If not I can answer it myself.